# Insert row from another tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, row

This has been frustrating me for a week.
I've made three table view controllers so far:

1. `navigationViewController`
2. `TableViewController`
3. `AddRowViewController`

The `AddRowViewController` gets accessed when I click a row from `TableViewController` called "+Add Row..."

I want the user to click "+Add Row", access `AddRowViewController`, and add a row in the bottom of the `TableViewController` by clicking the specified rows. Once it that's done, it will return to the `TableViewController`.

```
override func tableView (tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  switch indexpath.row {
    case 0:
      let MainTVC = TableViewController()
      MainTVC.RowNames.append("Name")
      MainTVC.insertRows(at:[MainTVC.newRowLoc], with:none)
      print("The Row Name is added below")
    case 1:
      print("Age")
    case 2:
      print("Gender")
    default:
      print("nil")
  }
}
```

I tried to add this code with the `MainTVC` instance, which I think is the reason why it doesn't add any rows to the TableView Controller.

Any thoughts at all?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example (best would be a Playground code snippet). Add Screenshots if necessary. And please add the important error message. please add code and error messages as text and not as images. format your source code if you mark all your code and tap on the `{}` button. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: did you really try to google before? keywords: uitableview tutorial add row

Comment: you should better ask a detailed question than for a tutorial at Stackoverview

Comment: you should read "This has been frustrating me for a week" before you post your comment

Comment: I didn't ask to add a row in a table, I asked to "INSERT ROW FROM ANOTHER TABLE", If you're going to question my research, I'll tell you that I didn't find anything.

Comment: just a note: you changed your question and the code snippet in the main time! thats a very different question now - you should note this befyore you advice me that i need to read your question carefully .... just my 23 cents

Comment: Please add more code. What happens in MainTVC? Your problem could also be that you are always creating a new instance of MainTVC.

Comment: and it is still the question: how to add a row in a TableViewController (if the info comes from a other tableview or form a normal UIView - still it is the problem `how to add a row in a TableView`

Comment: and your code snippet you provided before don't match with `This has been frustrating me for a week` and not show any results of thinking a week long

Comment: BTW: i removed my downvote because now it is a more clear question. see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### the problem

you create always a new instance of `TableViewController` in this line:

```
let MainTVC = MainTableViewController()
```

this `MainTVC` is then a second instance of the TableViewController. but you need to hold a reference to your existing mainTVC.

there are two ways to open a new controller:

#### 1) by code

when you create the `AddRowViewController` from your `TableViewController` by code then you can hold a reference to the TableViewController.

Example:

AddRowViewController:

```
class AddRowViewController {
    var weak mainTVC: MainTableViewController?


    func addRowToMainTVC(item: String{
       // let MainTVC = MainTableViewController() <-- you don't need it here you 
       //                                             you still have a reference
       mainTVC?.rowNames.append("Name") // <-- here you use the reference you hold
       

      // but i advice to put the logic how to insert into the MainVC
      // use for example the new addRow and not outside logic

      mainTVC?.addRow("Name")
}
```

MainTableViewController:

```
class MainTableViewController {

  // ...

  func showAddRowVC {
    let addRowVC = AddRowViewController()
    addRowVC.mainTVC = self // <-----
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addRowVC, animated: true) 
  }
  // ...

  func addRow(item: String){
    rowNames.apppend(item)
    self.reloadData() <-- for example you can say to the table to reload it self
  }

}
```

or you create a convenience initializer where you take a reference to the mainTVC

#### 2. by segue

if you switch to the new view by you can set the reference in the `prepareForSegue` function.

PS:
variables should be first letter lower case to distinct it from a class definition

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out and tell you the results once I'm done with my job.

Comment: if this solved your problem: please mark my answer as accepted (click on the big checkmark on the left side of my answer)